# How is Implicit finding the correct method to be invoked with generics when types are erased?

Tags: scala, generics, types, implicit, erasure

In my code below, I have a function `test` that takes in a object of type magnet and I have two implicit methods converting List[Int] to magnet and the other converting List[String] to magnet.

If JVM is supposed to loose the types in generics due to type erasure at run time, In my below code both the methods `fromListInt` and `fromListString` will look like List[Any] right? 
Because when I name both functions with same name I got the error `error: double definition:` suggesting that both List[Int] and List[String] are considered same.

how are the correct implicit methods found in this case when I pass List(0) and List("0") ?

```
scala> trait magnet {
     | def printSomething: Unit
     | }
defined trait magnet

scala> object magnet {
     | implicit def fromListInt(future: List[Int]): magnet = {
     | new magnet { def printSomething: Unit = println("test int") }
     | }
     | implicit def fromListString(future: List[String]): magnet = {
     | new magnet { def printSomething: Unit = println("test string") }
     | }
     | }
defined object magnet
scala> def test(in: magnet): Unit = {
     | in.printSomething
     | }
test: (in: magnet)Unit

scala> import magnet._
import magnet._

scala> test(List(0))
test int

scala> test(List("0"))
test string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicits are resolved at compile time, not at runtime. At compile time, nothing has been erased. Full type information is available to the compiler.

In a REPL, every time you type a line of code, you are compiling it before you are running it. `test(List(0))` gets converted by the compiler to something like `test(fromListInt(List(0)))`, and that what is compiled, and so that is the behavior you see. `test(List("0"))` gets converted by the compiler to something like `test(fromListString(List("0")))`, and so that is the behavior you see there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When I define the functions with same name, then why does it complain about double definition? Is it because compiler knows that since types will be erased both method signatures look alike and only one will be present in vtable?

Comment: it’s a good question! yes, an easy answer is that, if implemented directly, the two functions would have identical names and JVM types and functions must have unique signatures. but the scala compiler could mangle the names to embed the parameterized arg type to prevent this. why doesn’t it? one answer might be Java interoperability: mangled overloaded functions could not be straightforwardly callable from java or other JVM languages. another answer might be the feature was not worth the extra complexity, since programmers can just distinguish the names themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Implicits are resolved at compile time. At compile time types are not erased yet.

`test(List(0))` is actually `test(fromListInt(List(0)))`, `test(List("0"))` is actually `test(fromListString(List("0")))`.